# Don't rebuild webpack client bundle when the server is changed

Tags: webpack

I have a universal app with a client bundle served up from an express server using `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware`. The bundle has an include on the `/src/client` folder. When I make a change to the `/src/server` folder, it takes about 8 or 9 seconds to rebuild the client, even though I didn't change anything on the client.

Is it possible to avoid a client rebuild when I only modify a file outside of the webpack build? I'm thinking something like writing the in-memory build to the `/build` folder before the server restarts (or when idle), and then attempting to pull from the `/build` folder when the server starts up again.

Anyone accomplish something similar?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: yeah, I have a development build, production build, and server build. When i edit stuff on the server, i use the production build, which builds the clients & persists that to disk. Then a refresh (piping, etc) is only 2-3 seconds, which is the time it takes to restart the server.